# Table joining in mysql 8

Tags: mysql

I have seen similar questions, but I do not get the context of the code.
I have two table that I would like to join and then filter data from.  The first table we will call office and the second table we will call agents.  I need to join the office.office_name to the agents.first_name, agents.last_name, agents.mobilephone.  I then need to filter the results for all active agents sorted by office and agent last name.

```
SELECT office_name
From offices
INNER JOIN agents
ON offices.office_name = agents.first_name
```

is the text I have come up with so far, but it is only showing the office_name field with no data in it.

**Table agents:**

Columns:

```
agent_key int PK 
first_name varchar(20) 
last_name varchar(25) 
work_phone varchar(10) 
mobile_phone varchar(10) 
email_address varchar(50) 
license_number varchar(30) 
remarks varchar(1000)
```

**Table offices**:

Columns:

```
office_key int PK 
office_name varchar(50) 
address varchar(50) 
city varchar(30) 
state char(2) 
zip_code varchar(10) 
phone_number varchar(10) 
fax_number varchar(10) 
email_address varchar(50) 
remarks varchar(1000)
```

Comment: It would be suprising that an office name would match the first name of an agent. Please provide sample data and desired resuls (as tabular text) to clarify your requirement/

Comment: show some sample data and your expected results

Comment: Can you show how your tables are set up? Typically you want a foreign key ID rather than trying to join using strings

Comment: office_key, office_name, address, city, state, phone_number, fax_number, - ganet_key, first_name, last_name, work_phone, mobile_phone, licence_number

Comment: this is the question I am trying to answer ----- They will need a list of offices and the agents that are assigned to them. The listing will need to include the office name, agent first and last name, and agent mobile phone for all active agents sorted by office and agent last name.

Comment: My daughter Amazon is going to struggle to find employment elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your `agents` table needs an additional column such as `office_key int` to identify for each agent which office that agent is associated with (this is known as a "foreign key"). After you have done this, you should also add a *foreign key constraint* expressing this relationship as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE agents
   ADD FOREIGN KEY agents(office_key) REFERENCES offices(office_key)
   ON DELETE CASCADE
   ON UPDATE CASCADE
   ;
```

This will:

1. Prevent you from adding an `agents` row with a value of `office_key` that does not exist in the `offices` table.
2. If you delete an `offices` row, then all `agents` in that office will automatically be deleted. If you remove the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause from the above SQL, then it will be impossible to delete an `offices` row if it still has any corresponding `agents` rows with the same foreign key value. You decide on whether you want the `ON DELETE CASCADE` behavior or not.
3. If you update the `office_key` value in an `offices` row, all of the corresponding `agents` rows' `office_key` values will be updated accordingly.

Since all the column names on both tables are unique except for `office_key`, you can, but you don't have to, qualify the column names with the table name:

```
SELECT office_name,
       first_name,
       last_name /* add other columns as you see fit */
FROM offices INNER JOIN agents ON offices.office_key = agents.office_key
ORDER BY office_name, last_name /*, first_name */
```

**Update: to add office_key column to agents table:**

```
ALTER TABLE agents
   ADD office_key int not null after agent_key
   ;
```

Comment: Thanks and this is over my head, but know its saying Error code 1072: Key column 'office_key' doesnt exist in table.

Comment: Did you add `office_key` as an additional column to your `agents` table as I indicated in the very first sentence of my answer? I also changed the order of the tables in the JOIN. This has no effect on the results; it's just more logical to me and is the same order you had the tables.

Comment: OK after reading your comments, I do not think I did, may I ask what the syntax would be for that

Comment: I've updated the answer with the SQL (I hope it works; if not look up the syntax in the MySql manual). Also run the other SQL I had specified afterwards that adds the foreign key constraint **after you have initialized the new office_key column.**

Comment: Thanks Booboo, I was able to go into the agents table, add the information, insert new information into fields and ran without any issues.

Comment: Did you retrieve what you needed? You need to initialize the office_key columns with meaningful values and then run the other sql to add the foreign key constarint.

Comment: Yes I believe it is working, I need to edit the agents fields as I have 6 users with the last name doe.

Comment: its not sorting by sorted by office and agent last name, its sorting by office, but not last name.Office 2 Jane Zeiger 6184562225
Office 3 Scott Anneblle 6183453333
Office 4 Michelle Doe 6182654444
Office 5 Tammy Stevenson 6182565555
Office 6 Nick Micheals 6185896666

Comment: It is sorting correctly. You need to understand what it means to sort by office_name, last_name. It will output Office 2 and all its agents before it outputs Office 3 and all of its agents. In outputting all of the Office 2 agents, the agents will be sorted by last name. Try sorting by last_name, office. Then if there are two people with the same last name, the one with the alphbetically "smaller" office name will be output first, for example Office 2 before Office 3.

Comment: Think of it ask taking the office name and joining the last name together to form a single string and that is what is being used to sort. "Office 2Zeiger" comes before "Office 3Annebile".

Comment: Yes, I went in and readjusted the table to add 6 more people and assigned to different offices, then when sorting the data I was able to populate the fields correctly.  Thank you so much, just learning sql.